# Debugging TypeScript in VSCode steps into compiled JavaScript instead

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a TypeScript application (multiple files) in VSCode, however, when stepping into any other function, instead of taking me to its location in a .ts file, it takes me to the compiled .js file.
[This is a video of what happens, exactly.](https://giant.gfycat.com/VacantBewitchedHen.webm) (Stepping from main.ts into a function in client.ts should take me to client.ts, not client.js)

Versions:

```
VSCode: 1.30.2
Node.js: 11.6.0
TypeScript: 3.2.4
```

I've already tried using ts-node, and it had the same result.
Source maps *are* enabled.

- launch.json: https://github.com/wolfinabox/Entropy-API/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json
- tasks.json:    https://github.com/wolfinabox/Entropy-API/blob/master/.vscode/tasks.json
- tsconfig.json: https://github.com/wolfinabox/Entropy-API/blob/master/tsconfig.json
- Whole Project: https://github.com/wolfinabox/Entropy-API

I'd like to be able to debug TypeScript like most other languages in VSCode (Javascript, Python, etc). Step into functions and it takes me to the correct location, even if it's in another source file.

Comment: Try adding `"inlineSourceMap": true` to your `tsconfig.json` file. You might need to remove `"sourceMap": true` for it to be inline.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thanks for the suggestion; doesn't appear to have changed the debug behavior, though.

Comment: I have never tried to compile the codes as you did in typescript, but as you now, typescript is a superset of javascript. As we expect, all the codes are compiled into javascript. I think it is normal